# На сайте размыто фото, через панель разработчика становится чётким

Tags: html, css, wordpress, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изображение в карточке товара, сайт на Wordpress.

Открываю через панель разработки в Chrome c небольшим изменением размера экрана - фото становится чётким. Возвращаюсь к полной версии - становится размыто. Изменение размера на адаптив не влияет. Фото не меньше тега и не растягивается.

Ссылка https://oblako-sharov36.ru/product-category/shary-s-risunkom/

В чём может быть причина и как можно исправить?

Comment: Нечётная ширина окна в пикселях?

Comment: @andreymal, Окно было 296px, картинка 300px. Сменил ширину окна на 300px - всё равно размыто.

Comment: Что-то в моём хроме мне не удалось добиться размытого отображения

Comment: В ФФ тоже не увидел дефектов

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, размытия удалось избежать. 
Сменил размер блока с 296px на 300px, под картинку.
Убрал на 100% растяжение по ширине.

Помогло.